# Check if a value exists before deleting with prepared statement

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli, prepared-statement

I'd like to get notified when a movie does not exists. This represents a script to delete movies from the database.
This is a part of what I have now:

```
$title = $_POST["title"];
$delMovie = mysqli_prepare($link, "DELETE FROM movie WHERE title=?");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($delMovie, "s", $title);
if (mysqli_stmt_execute($delMovie)) {
    echo("Movie \"" . $title . "\" successfully deleted: ");
    echo(mysqli_stmt_affected_rows($delMovie) . " rows affected");
} else {
    echo("Error (" . mysqli_stmt_errno($delMovie) . "): ");
    echo(mysqli_stmt_error($delMovie));
}
mysqli_stmt_free_result($delMovie);
mysqli_stmt_close($delMovie);
mysqli_close($link);
```

When the movie does not exists, it still returns:

> Film "Movie1" successfully deleted: 0 rows affected

As you can see, it doesn't exist, but still returns "Successfully". How can I change this to show:

> Error: Movie does not exists in database

Comment: It returns successfully because the query didn't fail with an error. There was just no rows affected.

Comment: Why not just store `mysqli_stmt_affected_rows($delMovie)` in a variable and if == 0 echo out a different message. It doesn't hurt to just run the delete query and have no rows deleted. Then you are only running one query which would be quicker anyways.

Comment: The "shoot and see if you hit anything" approach to deleting is much, much better than the "test and conditionally delete" method since the latter is subject to ugly [race conditions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition) where your test might fail, but the record appears a moment later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about the following:

```
if (mysqli_stmt_affected_rows($delMovie) == 0) then
  echo "Error: Movie does not exists in database";
```

Just because mysql returns 0, doesn't mean you have to show the result as if it's more than one.

=============================================

You're only other option would be to

```
1) Do a select statement to check for existence
2) If not exists
   a) Show error
   b) Delete
       - If error deleting, show error
       - Else show success
```

or

```
1) Delete
    - If 0 rows affected or error, Show error message
    - Else show success
```

I think a variation on the second path makes for cleaner code.